# Inkscape PDF resizing

Tags: graphics, scaling, svg

I'm trying to include some PDF I saved in Inkscape and change the width and the height at the same time. Is this possible? I tried `\svgheight` and it did not take both values at the same time.

This is what I do

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \def\svgwidth{0.75\columnwidth} 
    \input{illustration.pdf_tex}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Example}
  \label{figillustration}
\end{figure}
```

In the past I had the option of doing this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=3.0in,width=3.8in,angle=0]{img_1.jpg}
    \caption{Example}
  \end{center}
\label{figgordon}
\end{figure}
```

(setting both the width and the height).

How do I do this now?

Comment: Is `illustration.pdf_tex` a PDF file or a TeX source document? If it's a PDF, you should be able to include it using `\includegraphics` if you correct the suffix to `.pdf`.

Comment: @Jake, the question refers to the pdf + TeX output from inkscape which does give a pdf_tex extension.

Comment: There is an added option in Inkscape 0.91: "Output page size".  You could select "use exported object's size" rather than "Use document's page size".

Answer (score 7):

Will this be useful?

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \resizebox{0.75\textwidth}{!}{\input{illustration.pdf_tex}}
  \caption{Example}
  \label{fig:illustration}
\end{figure}
```

Using `\begin{center}` gives extra vertical space. It is advisable to use `\centering`

May be [this](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) article is useful.

**Edit-1:**

From Inkscape you can export your diagram as tikz code. you have to install `inkscape2tikz` extension [from here](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/). Once installed, figures can be exported as tikz code (Extensions->Export->Export to TikZ path). Say you save the exported file as `figure.tex`. Now, in your latex main file you have to include this:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\resizebox{0.75\textwidth}{!}{\input{figure.tex}}
\caption{Caption of the figure} \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

You have to put `figure.tex` and your main latex file in the same folder or full path to figure.tex has to be specified like `\input{C:/figure-files/figure.tex}`. I always go by this method.

There is another way where you can export the figure as .pdf file (not as .pdf_tex) (file->save as->figure.pdf). Then you can include it like:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight]{figure.pdf}
\caption{Caption of the figure}
\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

But here if you change the font of the document, fonts in figure won't match properly. Also it is better to keep the `aspect ratio`. This is done by mentioning only `width` or `height` of the figure.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you checked the "PDF+LaTeX: Omit text in PDF, and create LaTeX file" option when exporting the file:

[image]

This creates two files: `.pdf` and `.pdf_tex`. The former is the non-text image in PDF form, while the latter contains the necessary image inclusion and text-related content, which should be rendered from within LaTeX. The problem is that the image inclusion looks like this:

```
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined
    \setlength{\unitlength}{595.27558594pt}
  \else
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}
  \fi
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined
  \makeatother
  \begin{picture}(1,1.4142857)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{tex.pdf}}%
     % <other text stuff>
    \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

Apart from some other nasty stuff, it defines `\svgwidth` if you don't define it. However, as is evident from the `\includegraphics` code, it only provides a `width` adjustment. Hence your problem with `\svgheight` not working.

Here are my suggestions:

- If you're interested in scaling the image proportionally, only set `\svgwidth`;
- If you don't have any text that requires conversion from Inkscape to LaTeX, export to `.pdf` *without* the "PDF+LaTeX: Omit text in PDF, and create LaTeX file" option checked. That way you can include the image as usual via `\includegraphics[width=<wd>,height=<ht>]{<file>}`; or
- Include the image using

  ```
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newsavebox{\myimage}% Box that will store image
    \begin{lrbox}{\myimage}
      \input{tex.pdf_tex}% Actual image and text
    \end{lrbox}
    \resizebox{3.8in}{3in}{\usebox{\myimage}}% Resize box
    % <caption> <label>
  \end{figure}
  ```